# Selenium WebDriver some url is not working

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm using selenium WebDriver it's working fine with every URL, but some URL is not opening `driver.get("base URL")` and that URL is opening when I'm opening manually in browser it's opening

Please give solution, Do I need to change some settings in Firefox or what?

Comment: Try giving example for *some URL* which are *Working* & *some URL* which are *not* working.

Comment: working url:  driver.get("http://google.com");driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945853/selenium-webdriver-some-url-is-not-working/33948000#33948000");  NON working url:driver.get("https://www385.americanexpress.com/tcauthweb/help.jsp");   non working url are some of my project link which is directly working fine in FF. do i have to change some settings in ff?

Comment: WebDriver api sends RESTfull request to Selenium server to execute a command. REST services uses http or https protocol for request/response. Hence when we call the url without mentioning the protocol prefix (in this case http), exception is thrown.

Comment: I tried to invoke the americanexpress URL with `http://americanexpress.com/tcauthweb/help.jsp` it is invoking site properly. You try it with Internet Explorer, it will work even for `www385.americanexpress.com/tcauthweb/help.jsp` but IE reformat the URL with `http://www385.americanexpress.com/tcauthweb/help.jsp`

Comment: did you solve?? If then how.

Answer (score 0):

For example if you are trying to access facebook, Instead of putting url as "www.facebook.com" , try putting "https://facebook.com".

Comment: i know that i tried that also it's not working please give some valuable suggestion. All website is working fine through selenium webdriver but some of my project website is not working can u help?

Comment: Please post your relevant code so we can take a look

Comment: @Shah : I think this is  a right solution as long as firefox is being used. FF can be downgraded to one lower version, but not sure if it will work.

Comment: @EashBhanu: You must be getting `f.QueryInterface is not a function` error. Try posting such details in your question. Or google it.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.Angular;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
    }

}
```

Comment: Please explain what this code does and how it solves OPs problem.